# Is firing a Polymer event slower than just calling the listener function directly?

Tags: javascript, polymer

Is there a significant amount of overhead with processing the event, particularly if the event only has one listener?

For example, is it slower to call it this way:

```
Polymer({
  'listeners': {
    'some-event': 'someFunc',
  },

  attached: function() {
    this.fire('some-event');
  },

  someFunc: function(event) {
   //do stuff..
  }
});
```

Versus:

```
Polymer({
  attached: function() {
    this.someFunc();
  },

  someFunc: function() {
   //do stuff..
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no notable difference when the event is fired synchronically (default) especially if the handler calls `event.stopPropagation()` so that the event doesn't bubble up and down the DOM. If the event is fired async, the handler is only called after the current event is fully processed (when the next task from the event queue is processed).
If there is no specific reason I would call the handler directly.

In relation to a request to the server, the difference doesn't matter at all. If you aim for high frame rate and have hundreds or thousands of such calls you might recognize a difference.